# How to implement Column Chooser in Jqgrid Boostrap

Tags: jqgrid

I remember there was COlumn chooser functionality in earlier version of JQGrid. I dont see any such function in Jqgrid bootstrap now.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use?

Comment: This is Guriido jqGrid JS .. This feature is not available in Bootstrap version